# Facebook shared button - cache

Tags: html, facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I have a 'Share on Facebook' button on my website. 
When I click the button, "Share on Facebook" window appears. In window I need to see image of dish, that located on this page. But sometimes image is not image of dish, but other any image from page.

For example, page from which I want to share on facebook looks like this 1.png. In "Share on Facebook" window it appears with other image (2.png).

Meta tags on page:

```
  <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPOj8cgO4dDE3R-mqqxlWj6b1AZHqPbkmLxZ0bFDHQiJYfA6Jqwg" />
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRPOj8cgO4dDE3R-mqqxlWj6b1AZHqPbkmLxZ0bFDHQiJYfA6Jqwg" />
```

Where the error can be?

Comment: You do not specify `Meta tags on page`. There is nothing after the colon.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/